# How to get which element is clicked in customized list view item in android ?

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I have a customized list item with 2 `Buttons` ( save , share) in a `ListView`.

How to get which `Button` is clicked in list item in `onItemClick()` method ?

Like:

```
      ListView
----------------------------
[Text]
[SAVE BUTTON1][SHARE BUTTON2]
-----------------------------
[Text]
[SAVE BUTTON1][SHARE BUTTON2]
-----------------------------
[Text]
[SAVE BUTTON1][SHARE BUTTON2]
-----------------------------
-
-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

set `Tag` to your `Button` in the `getView()` method of your `ListView`

```
btn.setTag(position);
```

then set `OnClickListener` to your button,

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button position is: "+v.getTag(),
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom adapters you should use `View.OnClickListener` and set it to each individual element `Button` using `setOnClickListener()` method.

the `onItemClick()` is part of `OnItemClickListener` that only responds to click on the whole view. This is usually used for simpler lists using one of the default adapters.

Comment: If i use setOnClickListener(), how to get the data associated with the list item in Listener function.

Comment: every `View` in Android have methods `setTag(Object)` and `getTag()`. Those can be used to store any object you want. So let's say your adapter is an `ArrayAdapter<Book>` you can store each individual book inside the view itself. That way during `onClick(View v)` you can `Book b = (Book) v.getTag();`

Comment: I am using the 'SimpleCursorAdaptor' ,  directly from sqlite fetching the data and providing it as adaptor for the list view. How to set the object, as data us coming from the database directly..

Comment: The method is still the same. For example, if you need an ID to save, you can put the String with the ID in the tag. If you need more than that, you can use a `HashMap` to put all the values you need, or create a Class just to hold those values.

Comment: followed the [source](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)